# automatically generate for each row of Google Sheets to a Slides template (mail merge) and safe in a folder on drive? using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, mailmerge, google-slides-api

I want that Apps Script to automatically generate a new set of slides using data from a Sheets document which has rows of the different information I want inserted into a Slides template replacing the placeholder tags. I want it to do it instantly for each row inside the table with one action, so if there are 10 rows, 10 sets of Slides documents will be generated.

Everything works as it but i get an time aout error from the script because i have about 600 rows and more.

My goal is to separate the rows for processing and safe the Generated slides in an separate created folder in drive named Cerificates.

And that is the point i dont no how to do it. So i hope for your Help. Thx for your Time

And that is the point i dont no how to do it. So i hope for your Help. Thx for your Time.

```
This is the code for the script:

function mailMergeSlidesFromSheets() {
  // Load data from the spreadsheet
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();
  var sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

  // Save the header in a variable called header
  var header = sheetContents.shift();

  // Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
  // We'll use this array to save links to Google Slides.
  var updatedContents = [];

  // Add the header to the array that will be written back
  // to the sheet.
  updatedContents.push(header);

  // For each row, see if the 4th column is empty.
  // If it is empty, it means that a slide deck hasn't been
  // created yet.
  sheetContents.forEach(function(row) {
    if(row[14] === "") {
      // Create a Google Slides presentation using
      // information from the row.
      var slides = createSlidesFromRow(row);
      var slidesId = slides.getId();
   
      // Create the Google Slides' URL using its Id.
      var slidesUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${slidesId}/edit`;

      // Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
      // to the updatedContents array to be written back to the sheet.
      row[14] = slidesUrl;
      updatedContents.push(row);
    }
  });

  // Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
  dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);

}

function createSlidesFromRow(row) {
 // Create a copy of the Slides template
 var deck = createCopyOfSlidesTemplate();

 // Rename the deck using the firstname and lastname of the student
 deck.setName(row[4] + " " + row[9] + row[3]);

 // Replace template variables using the student's information.
    deck.replaceAllText("{{id}}", row[0]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{tag}}", row[3]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{besetzung}}", row[4]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{beginn}}", row[5]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{ende}}", row[6]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{halle}}", row[7]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{stand}}", row[8]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{firma}}", row[2]);
    deck.replaceAllText("{{veranstaltung}}", row[9]);
    deck.getSlides()[0].getShapes().find(s => s.getText().asString().trim().toUpperCase() == "{{IMAGE}}").replaceWithImage(`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=${row[12]}`);

 return deck;
}

function createCopyOfSlidesTemplate() {
 //
 var TEMPLATE_ID = "19PKvWoDtbeVHcqm4DnWUxRx1OBO817uG3cL5Ox-dQoo";

 // Create a copy of the file using DriveApp
 var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy();

 // Load the copy using the SlidesApp.
 var slides = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());

 return slides;
}

function onOpen() {
 // Create a custom menu to make it easy to run the Mail Merge
 // script from the sheet.
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Create BWN by Pavlos")
   .addItem("Create Slides","mailMergeSlidesFromSheets")
   .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Can i see the full error message please

Comment: Maximum run time exceeded  i translated it in englisch from because it shows me in my language.

Comment: And this error message: Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 601.
mailMergeSlidesFromSheets @ Code.gs:38

Comment: hard coding numbers for your arrays is probably whats  causing your isuse.

Comment: thx but how can i fix it? I am really frustated because it worked one time and stopped generating after 38 slides.

Comment: I tried to change if(row[14] === "")  to if(row[16] === "")  and  row[16] = slidesUrl;  but same error and the genrated slides url are not apearing in the sheet.

Comment: If you have reached the execute time limit, you won't be able to go any further, please see : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=fr, about the second error ```The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range``` you just have to change ```dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);``` to ```dataRange.offset(sheetContents.length, 0, updatedContents.length, updatedContents[0].length).setValues(updatedContents)``` but that won't change your first problem

Comment: Can I ask you about your actual situation? 1. In your situation, when an error related to the timeout occurs, how many new Google Slides were created? 2. When you run your script, do you directly run the script with the script editor? From these results, I would like to think of a direction for achieving your goal.

Comment: @Tanaike Thx for your reply. The script is now not running anymore after pasting the code from @ Waxim . By the way @ Waxim thank you for your reply. Before then the script created about 38 slides correctly and then the 2 error appers. I really dont no now what else i can do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that 38 Google Slides are created in 6 minutes. Is my understanding correct? I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand `the 2 error appers`. And also, I couldn't understand the method for executing your script.

Comment: @Tanaike for Question 1. I think i created t trying the script 3 times together over 280 slides. 2. i have run the script directly with the script editor and later direkt on the sheet. Now after inserting Waxims code the script is running at the sheet without any error but no slides are created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that 280 Google Slides are created by 6 minutes. And also, I understood that you execute your script by the script editor. And, can I ask you about the detail of `the 2 error appers`?

Comment: Thank you for your effort and your help. the answer for your question is yes. The created 38 slides in 6 minutes. Now the script is running no error appers and no slides are creating. would it help to paste the code again? and if so how can i do that?

Comment: I have typed the code again in an new function. the code is runnig and now i have this error   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceWithImage')
createSlidesFromRow @ Code.gs:59
(Anonym) @ Code.gs:24
mailMergeSlidesFromSheets @ Code.gs:20

Comment: Hi everyone sorry for beeing to long ofline to give you a feedback. Ihave made the mods from Waxim Corp and @Tanaike and the script is running. Everything is inserted to the tags fto the slides including the Qr Image. But if i run the script it only makes 3 slides and the sript finishes the job. On the script editor is no error occuring. The script generates from the sheet 3 slides and starts from the last row. for example: the script dont start generating from the row 2 to generating downwards it start from the row 601 and ads every time dowwarts a copied row starting from header.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: no the issue is not solved because i have the problem with the time out for Appscript. The script generates in 6 minutes 38 slides and stops. I dont know now how to implement in my code tha the script starts again from tha last created .